# Drawing an arrow or a solid dot on a curve?

Tags: plotting

[image]

I want to draw arrows and the solid dot like in this picture on a curve.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it with `Epilog`:

```
f[x_] := 2 - 2 Sin[x] + x;
x0 = 4;
δ1 = 0.2;
δ2 = 0.23;
γ = 1.1;

Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 7}, 
 Epilog -> {Pink, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x0, f[x0]}], Darker[Pink], 
   Arrow[{{{x0 - γ δ1, f[x0 - γ δ1]}, {x0 - δ1, f[x0 - δ1]}}, 
          {{x0 + γ δ2, f[x0 + γ δ2]}, {x0 + δ2, f[x0 + δ2]}}}]}]
```

[image]

Here `δ1` and `δ2` mean the distances to arrows along the axis x, `γ` tweaks arrow slopes.